# save html color table in mysql

Tags: html, mysql

I am making a website where users can post quilting patterns on a standard HTML table. I created a table where users can click to change the color of a cell of an HTML table, but the changes don't last. Thus, I want to save the entire HTML table to a SQL database. I looked up other posts on saving HTML tables, but they all deal with values (and changing them). I have no values. All I want to do is to save the colors.

Comment: *"I have no values. All I want to do is to save the colors."* - Then those are the values you want to save.  What have you tried and where are you stuck?  How is your MySQL table (or tables) structured?  Have you written any server-side code to save your data?  How are you sending your data to the server?

Comment: The user's table column is c1,c2,c3, etc and rows are r1,r2r,r3. Each row of the sql database has a unique user. I tried columns where it was c1r1, c1r2,c1r3...c2r1, c2r3 etc, but I don't know how to translated the user's clicks to change the sql database value.

Comment: *"how to translated the user's clicks to change the sql database value"* - Well, if it's a click event then you'd use JavaScript to respond to that click event.  But you still need to work with some server-side language/framework/etc. to actually save the data to a database.  You'll likely want to choose one and start with some tutorials on that.  There are a few different approaches you can take, such as posting a form with the values to save after all changes vs. making an AJAX request to update each individual value change.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "posting a form with the values to save after all changes"

Comment: HTML can have "forms" which contain various ways of inputting data.  Those forms would have something called a "submit button" which would post the data in the form input elements to the server.  Tutorials on HTML, and on any server-side web application language, will cover this.

Answer (score 0):

Their is a javascript function to get attribute of any html tags
Here u need to use the function to get the color attribute of the respective table and store it in a variable which later can be inserted into database using php function.

ex:
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("H1")[0].getAttribute("class");

reference link:https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_getattribute.asp